# Instance of class shared between static libraries (obj files)

Tags: c++, class, static-libraries, header-files

I have a C++ application with the following 3 files:

```
// sample.h
#ifndef sample_h
#define sample_h
#include <stdio.h>
namespace mynamespace {
    class sample {
        public:
            void myprintf(const char* tmp);
    };
}
#endif

// sample.cpp
#include "sample.h"
void mynamespace::sample::myprintf(const char* val) {
    printf(val);
}

// main.cpp
#include "sample.h"
int main() {
    mynamespace::sample sample1; // How to omit this line?
    sample1.myprintf("Hello world!");
}
```

Is it possible to remove the instantiation of sample1 object from main.cpp, and to have it already available (coming from the static library "sample.obj")?

If I move that line to sample.h, then the error I get during compilation is:

```
"class mynamespace::sample sample1" already defined in sample.obj
```

If I move that line to sample.cpp, then the error message is:

```
'sample1': undeclared identifier
```

Actually I understand why both errors occur, I just don't know what is the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use static declaration:

in sample.h

```
namespace mynamespace{
class sample {
public:
    static sample sample1;
    void myprintf(const char* tmp);
};
static sample& sample1 = sample::sample1;
}
```

then in sample.cpp

```
mynamespace::sample mynamespace::sample::sample1;
```

from main.cpp
access the variable

```
mynamespace::sample::sample1.myprintf("");
mynamespace::sample1.myprintf("");
```

Comment: If I add the above-mentioned line to sample.cpp, it will result in 5 compilation errors. First is: identifier "sample" is undefined

Comment: add mynamespace:: before declaration sorry I missed it

Comment: Thanks, it is working, and I appreciate this solution, but there must be a briefer one, because when we use the operator << with std::cout, then we can see that the operator-overloading is defined in cout, and the invokation syntax is nothing like std::cout::cout1. std is a namespace, not a class.

Comment: add reference to sample1 outside class will do the job

Comment: In this case I get a very similar compilation error, which I originally had: "class mynamespace::sample & mynamespace::sample1" already defined in sample.obj

Comment: add static before reference declaration will solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

[Specify an `extern` storage class in the header file](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration):

```
namespace mynamespace {

    // ...

    extern sample sample1;
}
```

And then define it normally in `sample.cpp`:

```
mynamespace::sample sample1;
```

It's possible that on some compilers/operating systems it will be necessary to specify something else, something that's compiler-specific, in order to get external linkage to a data symbol in a library. This is beyond the scope of the C++ standard. Consult your compiler's documentation for more information.

Comment: You may be right about what's within the scope of the standard, but unfortunately neither GCC nor MSVC++ can compile it. So I will need to do further investigation